# How do I access the command line arguments used to invoke Ansible?

Tags: ansible, command-line-interface

I'd like to print out the command line arguments used to invoke `ansible-playbook`. E.g., if I do

`ansible-playbook foo.yml -e bar=quux`

, I'd like to have access to the above string, so that I can do as a task

`- shell: slack_notify.sh "{{ ansible_cli_invocation }}"`

where `ansible_cli_invocation` is a string with the value `"ansible-playbook foo.yml -e bar=quux"`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: FYI there is [a Slack module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/slack_module.html) you can use instead of your shell script.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it out of the box.
But you can write a tiny action plugin:

```py
from ansible.plugins.action import ActionBase
import sys

class ActionModule(ActionBase):

    TRANSFERS_FILES = False

    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
        return { 'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': { 'argv': sys.argv } }
```

Save it as `./action_plugins/get_argv.py` and also make an *empty* file `./library/get_argv.py`.
This creates local action `get_argv` that populates `argv` fact with arguments list.

Then in your playbook:

```
- get_argv:
- shell: slack_notify.sh "{{ argv | join(' ') }}"
```

Comment: I had to create `action_plugins` and `library` folders at the location of my playbook that I was running (I tried putting the folders in the ansible project root, and ansible could not find the module).

Comment: @opert they should be in the folder from where you execute ansible or you can place them somewhere else and set paths in your ansible.cfg

Comment: I suppose I forgot to add that I have playbooks in a non-standard `./playbooks` subfolder (hence my comment above). Thanks for clarifying; the upstream docs do mention that you can set the location of the library folder in ansible.cfg and such, but I'll try to avoid further customizations if possible.

Comment: @opert in this case, you should place them in `./playbooks/action_plugins/` and `./playbooks/library`

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear in my first comment, but that's exactly what I did; I was merely commenting for posterity what I did to get it to work.