# Is there any way to validate whether a file is passed as extra vars in ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have an ansible playbook which requires a JSON file to be passed as a `--extra-vars` (or `-e` ) from the command line. I would like to know if there is any way that I can add a validation task in my playbook to confirm that such a file is passed.

I have checked ***hostvars*** and did not find any parameter that stores such value or name of the file. It directly loaded the variables present inside the file.

I tried `echo !!` (to fetch the command history) using ***command*** and ***shell*** modules which didn't work either.

Sample command

`ansible-playbook test.yml -e@input_vars.json`

I want a task that will fail the execution if the JSON file is not passed in `--extra-vars`. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you just check if expected variables are defined? (task that prints failure can have conditional `when: my_var is undefined`)

Comment: Yes, that I'm already doing. I wanted to know if it's possible to check if some JSON file is being passed from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if it is not possible to find out where and when a variable was defined, it might be possible to check the content of the CLI option(s).

Whereby for the CLI options `--tags`, `--skip-tags` and `--limit` the [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) `ansible_run_tags`, `ansible_skip_tags` and `ansible_limit` are available, to [access the command line argument `--extra-vars` used to invoke Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502543/) one would need to drop a tiny [Custom Action Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39504899/6771046).

After that a sample playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Gather Arguments Values
    get_argv:

  - name: Show values
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.argv }}"
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook --extra-vars="test=test" extraVars.yml
```

results into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show values] *************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  - --extra-vars=test=test
  - extraVars.yml
```

> *... if there is any way that I can add a validation task in my playbook to confirm that such a file is passed ... I want a task that will fail the execution if the JSON file is not passed in `--extra-vars` ...*

You would need than just to include a check of the [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) and [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts).

**Further Documentation**

- [Action plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/action.html)
- [Developing plugins - Action plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-actions)
- [Action plugins included with Ansible Core](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action)
- [Python `sys` - System-specific parameters and functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

---

The above approach gives also the opportunity to check for multiple extra vars files like in the problem [What is the variable order/precedence in case of multiple 'extra_vars' files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70851501/6771046)

```bash
ansible-playbook extraVars.yml --extra-vars="test=test" -e="test=TEST"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show values] *************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  - extraVars.yml
  - --extra-vars=test=test
  - -e=test=TEST

TASK [Show content of var 'test'] *************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method, function, lookup plugin, special variable, etc. to find out where a variable comes from. Without knowing the run-string you also can't tell whether extra variables are used or not.

The simplest method to determine whether extra variables are used might be based on the fact that extra vars are the highest [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). For example, test if extra vars overrode a variable

```yaml
shell> cat input_vars.yml
extra_vars: true
var1: foo
var2: bar
```

Declare the variable *extra_vars* also in the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat test.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    extra_vars: false
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: extra_vars|bool
        fail_msg: Extra vars missing. End of play.
    - debug:
        msg: |
          var1: {{ var1 }}
          var2: {{ var2 }}
```

The playbook fails if you run it without extra vars

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: extra_vars|bool
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Extra vars missing. End of play.
```

The playbook will continue if extra vars are used

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test.yml -e@input_vars.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: foo
    var2: bar
```

Comment: I'm already doing validation of the vars inside the file. I was just looking for a way to validate the argument passed which is <file>.json and not the vars inside. Sounds like it's not really possible.