# How to know where a variable is located

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

So I have this playbook .yml

```
- name: "{{ __tpfx }}Configure LDAP | configure harbor ldap"
  become: yes
  uri:
    url: "{{ harbor_ldap__fqdn ~ '/api/v2.0/configurations' }}"
    url_username: "{{ harbor_ldap__url_username }}"
    url_password: "{{ harbor_ldap__url_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    use_proxy: false
    method: PUT
    force_basic_auth: yes
```

Now I want to know where the variable `"{{ harbor_ldap__url_password }}"` is stored or located (directory), how can I find this?

Comment: You can always `grep -R "harbor_ldap__url_password" *` in the main playbook directory

Comment: It really depends on various factors: if it's just a playbook or part of a role, etc ...

Usually if it's in a Playbook it should be in the vars section or include_vars ... it also could be in the group_vars or host_vars directories ...

As @ZumodeVidrio said, best to perform a grep in the tree to double check.

Comment: The problem is idk where the main playbook directory is

Comment: its weird, because you provided your playbook.yml and you do not know whereyour playbook directory is located.  @ZumodeVidrio comment is the best approach to figure that out.

Comment: Does the thread about "[How to find out where a variable comes from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72937001/)" answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It might be in an `inventory.yml` file. Or at the top of your `playbook.yml` file in the `vars:` section.

Try to look for it.

Comment: Or in many other places according [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) and [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).