# How to pass value to variable in list, to pick one by one using command "ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-var variable1=ntpd,crond,sysconf"

Tags: linux, ansible

I tried to pass value manually to a specific variable by using command

```bash
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-var variable1=ntpd
```

Can you please help me to know how to pass value to variable in list, to pick one by one using command?

I've tried as below did not work

```bash
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-var "variable1=ntpd,crond,sysconf"
```

Tried as but no luck

```bash
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-var "variable1=ntpd,crond,sysconf"
ansible-playbook test.yml  -e '{"variable1":["ntpd", "crond"]}'
```

The playbook should pick 1st value as `ntpd` and then second value as `crond` and so on.

Comment: As an adhoc test => `-ansible localhost --extra-var '{"variable1":["ntpd","crond","sysconf"]}' -m debug -a var=variable1[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look into the following minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show provided content and type
    debug:
      msg:
       - "var1 contains {{ var1 }}"
       - "var1 is of tpye {{ var1 | type_debug  }}"
```

which will called with

```bash
ansible-playbook extra.yml --extra-vars="var1=a,b,c"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show provided content and type] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - var1 contains a,b,c
  - var1 is of tpye unicode
```

I understand that you like to get a list out of it for further processing. Since there is a string of comma separated values this is quite simple to achieve, just split the string on the separator.

```yaml
  - name: Create list and loop over elements
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ var1 | split(',') }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Create list and loop over elements] ******
ok: [localhost] => (item=a) =>
  msg: a
ok: [localhost] => (item=b) =>
  msg: b
ok: [localhost] => (item=c) =>
  msg: c
```

---

As the example show packages names, the use cause might be to install or validate packages and which are provided in a list of comma separated values (`pkgcsv`).

In example for the [`yum` module – Manages packages with the yum package manager](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html) and because of the [Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#notes)

> *When used with a `loop:` each package will be processed individually, it is much more efficient to pass the list directly to the `name` option.*

one should better proceed further with

```yaml
- name: Install a list of packages with a list variable
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: "{{ pkgcsv | split(',') }}"
```

or, as the module has the capabilities to do so, one could also leave the CSV just as it is

```yaml
- name: Install a list of packages with a list variable
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: "{{ pkgcsv }}"
```

**Further Reading**

As this could be helpful for other or in future cases.

- [Is there any way to validate whether a file is passed as extra vars in `ansible-playbook`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72939226/6771046)